# Is it possible to define a maven plugin which runs on all phases of the maven life cycle

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

Is it possible to create a maven plugin which runs on all phases of the maven life cycle.

I would like to create a plugin which currently needs to run on some parts of the life cycle however in the future may need to run on other parts of the life cycle. I would like for users to be able to simply change the version of the plugin so that the newer version of the plugin automatically starts running on new life cycles it now supports.

I think I could do this by making a MOJO for every life cycle phase of maven and have each mojo have its own unique goal. The pom would be ugly and would need to include the plugin and the goals section would need to have a goal for every MOJO.

The pom would look a little ugly:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>bar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>a</goal>
                <goal>goal</goal>
                <goal>for</goal>
                <goal>every</goal>
                <goal>mojo</goal>
                <goal>and</goal>
                <goal>a</goal>
                <goal>mojo</goal>
                <goal>for</goal>
                <goal>every</goal>
                <goal>phase</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Does a better way exist?

Comment: First question: What kind of plugin are you thinking of? And why is it needed to run in so many lifecycle phases?

Comment: I second @khmarbaise: Can you please edit your question and add some explanation what this plugin should be for? It seems like there are better solutions for your original problem.